# Dashboard architecture - Angular JS + React JS + Node JS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, architecture

I am starting on a **Dashboard** where Angular and React is used on the Client side while Node js is used as the Server side.

I was going through some architecture and i found this:

**View:**

```
<html ng-app="my-dashboard">
  <body>
    <div class="Some structuring thing">
      <ng-include src="my-header.html"></ng-include>
    </div>
    <div class="Some other thing">
      <ng-include src="my-sidebar.html"></ng-include>
    </div>

    etc...

  </body>
</html>
```

**Controllers:**

```
<div ng-controller="my-header-text">
  <p ng-bind="title">

  etc...
</div>
<div ng-controller="my-header-login">
  <p ng-click="login()">Login</p>

  etc...

</div>
```

From these pieces of code, **is it possible to pave way for an app similar to [this](http://angularsignalrdashboardlouiebacaj.azurewebsites.net/index.html#)?**

Thanks.

Comment: Well sure, I don't see why not? Maybe look up things like socket.io for real time communication (websocket), in order to connect your front and backend.

Comment: @Kristof Is this the best practice or is there any other way that we can do this? Am speaking in terms of Angular architecture :)

Comment: Well, it's a recommendation. Back when I made something in node.js it was the least headache to use socket.io for front/backend communication. You should look up websocket. It will try to use that, and otherwise degrade gracefully.

Comment: @Kristof I meant the code above, used to toggle between the tabs :) Other ways i can think of is to use ng-hide, to hide the tabs or set Routes for the pages.